# Access same content tree by using different URL in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

In my current project we need to create a microsite under curent sitecore site for extra branding.

Basically, what I want is using exactily same content tree for both:
**www.domian.com** and **www.domain.com/microsite**
we may need to load different layout for them.

Result:
I endded up using VirtualFolder, it worked for me for minimal available level.

Comment: You mean that the main site and the microsite have same content only different layout? cause it doesn't make that much sense to me.. ?

Comment: @ub1k basically, the main reason is we want to have a little different tailored branding but keep most of the structure and content unchanged comparing with the main website. dose that answer your question?

Comment: well what I'm thinking is.. shouln't it be just some alternate styling applied on the main site ? cookie-based switchable css'es?

Comment: James one is a elegent solution that I would recommend, however because i am stuck at 6.1. I end upusing "virtual folder"+"redirection"+"layout manipulation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a `microsite.domain.com` site, pointing at the same content path. Then in the web.config set it to use a different device (you can set this in the site element). You can then specify an alternate layout for each template for this device (device=default uses layout1, device=microsite uses micrositelayout).

This won't give you the `www.domain.com/microsite` URL structure but it will enable simple switching between layouts for the same content.

See [Varying content and presentation by host name in Sitecore 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836682/varying-content-and-presentation-by-host-name-in-sitecore-6-4)